# Displaying entries per category in ExpressionEngine

Tags: categories, expressionengine

So, I've searched, and found a few posts that kinda get me what I want, but it still doesn't quite work. This post especially seemed closest to what I was trying to achieve, and I built my code off of it: http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/168142/

To explain; I have a series of entries, each entry is assigned to only one category. I'd like to list out these categories and, beneath each category, list out the entries with one of their custom fields. Like so:

- Category 1

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
- Category 2

  - Item 1
  - Item 2

So, here's my code as it stands now, which lists out the categories, but doesn't spit out any of the entries at all:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="faq-question" style="linear"}
    <section class="faq-category-container closed">
        <h1 class="faq-category-header"><a href="#">{category_name}</a></h1>
        <dl>
    {exp:query sql="

        SELECT title, url_title AS urlt, cat_id

        FROM exp_channel_titles

        NATURAL JOIN exp_category_posts

        WHERE channel_id = '7' AND cat_id = '{category_id}'

        ORDER BY title ASC"
    }
        {embed="jazz-camp/faq-cat-list" faqlink="{urlt}"}
    {/exp:query}
        </dl>
    </section><!-- end .faq-category -->
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

And the embedded template it references:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="faq-question" url_title="{embed:faqlink}"}<!-- entry -->
    <dt>{title}</dt>
    <dd>
        {faq_content}
    </dd>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, here's what I ended up with at the end (courtesy of some help over at the EE boards):

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="faq-camp" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
    <section class="faq-category-container closed">
        <h1 class="faq-category-header"><a href="#">{category_name}</a></h1>
        <div class="faq-questions-container">
            <dl>
    {embed="jazz-camp/faq-cat-list" faqlink="{category_id}" faqparent="faq-camp"}
            </dl>
        </div><!-- end .faq-questions-container -->
    </section><!-- end .faq-category -->
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

And as for the embed, it looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:faqparent}" category="{embed:faqlink}" dynamic="no"}<!-- entries -->
    <dt>{title}</dt>
    <dd>
        {faq_answer}
    </dd>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The reason for the embed has to do with how things are pulled in with regards to getting the correct channel entries; simply having the `{exp:channel:entries}` inline in the page didn't quite work.

Answer (score 14):

This may be a very basic example of what you're after:

```
{exp:channel:categories style="linear"}
  <h1>{category_name}:</h1> 
  {exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}" dynamic="no"}
    <p>{my_custom_field}</p>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic version of what I ended up with. I've created another answer to demonstrate what I finally used.

Comment: you saved a strand of my sanity tonight, thank you for posting.

Comment: This example works when you add dynamic="no" to your channel:entries tag.

Answer (score 1):

The Category Archive tag might be helpful to you:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/category_archive.html